Pyspark force schema while reading parquet
I have a parquet source with the 'Year' column as long and I have specified it as int in my table. While reading parquet I specify the schema of the table to force it but it gives an error instead.
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .schema(spark.table(f'{CATALOG_NAME}.{BRONZE_SCHEMA}.{SLA_TARGET}').schema)
    .parquet(RAW_EXTERNAL_LOCATION_PATH + f"/{SLA_TARGET}/{SLA_TARGET}.parquet")
)

It gives the error
SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException: column: [Year], physicalType: INT64, logicalType: int

I don't want to read and then cast it. Why can't it forcefully cast the column? I am using Databricks - 14.3LTS, Spark - 3.5.0
I don't think that we need to do vectorizedReader to false, because according to this blog that is required for decimal types and not for others. But still even if I do spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false") then it is unable to read parquet file correctly and gives the error - FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@satrinitydevgfsst01.dfs.core.windows.net/gfs_reporting_raw/sla_target/sla_target.parquet. Possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted. Caused by: ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file abfss:/...

The solution probably lies in the fact that parquet is a columnar store with fixed data types. It is made to efficiently store data with compression and uses the data type among others to do that.
So when reading the data, it doesn't need any schema as no interpretation of the data is done. So adding a schema would essentially be the same as casting, it wouldn't be interpreting the data with those types.
Therefore, casting will probably be your only option unfortunately. In your case, you could write a script that iterates over your desired schema and does casting based on that, so you don't have to explicitly cast individual columns if you don't want to.
